# how to disply the names of persons who donated blood ...they should be have 30 days over comparing to today date

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing a blood bank project. I have to display the donors who are donating blood.

The days should be 30 or greater days older than today (else dont display), eg

donated date  :01-11-2010
   today date    :09-12-2010

then display. The gap should be 30 or more days but not less than 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @astander but I would change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE DonatedDate <= DATEADD(d,-30,getdate())
```

That way if you have an index on DonatedDate it should use it depending on the rest of your query

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using [DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Donated TABLE(
        ID INT,
        DonatedDate DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Donated SELECT 1, '01 Jan 2010'
INSERT INTO @Donated SELECT 2, '01 Mar 2010'
INSERT INTO @Donated SELECT 3, '01 Aug 2010'
INSERT INTO @Donated SELECT 4, '01 Dec 2010'

SELECT  *
FROM    @Donated
WHERE   DATEDIFF(day, DonatedDate, GETDATE()) > 30
```